# How do I turn my formula (that I drag down) into an arrayformula (or equivalent)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HM0tI3u3ewLNS8RPTbOyzvO1yEhffJnbjeMo1meg8mQ/edit#gid=1512335937) with 2 sheets: `Watchlist2` and `stockPrices`:

- In `Watchlist` I keep a list of stock tickers that I want to calculate the ytd, 1-year, and 5-year price change for
- The current price comes from `googlefinance()` function; the historial prices from the `stockPrices` sheet

**Watchlist:**

[image]

**stockPrices:**

[image]

To calculate the ytd, 1-year and 5-year price changes respectively, I succesfully use the following formula (in this case: for the 5 year change):

```
=iferror(((C2-INDEX(stockPrices!$B$2:$J, $I$9, B2))/INDEX(stockPrices!$B$2:$J, $I$9, B2))*100,"NA")
```

I drag this formula down to get all the price changes. But now I want to only have a formula in row 2 (in cell `D2`, `E2`, and `F2`) that copies down. So I thought to use `arrayformula()` (in this case the formula in `D2`:

```
=arrayformula(IFERROR(((C2:C10 - INDEX(stockPrices!$B$2:$J, $I$6, C2:C10))/INDEX(stockPrices!$B$2:$J, $I$6, C2:C10))*100, "NA"))
```

- The good news is that the formula indeed copies down
- The bad news is that it displays `NA` for every ticker, instead of the real change.

What am I doing wrong that this formula is not giving the expected result?

Comment: `=arrayformula(IFERROR(((C2:C10 - INDEX(stockPrices!$B$2:$J, $I$6, B2:B10))/INDEX(stockPrices!$B$2:$J, $I$6, B2:B10))*100, "NA"))` works in your sheet

Comment: btw, `C2:C10/INDEX(stockPrices!$B$2:$J, $I$6, B2:B10)-1` is safer in terms of reducing unnecessary access/computation/memory and in producing a useable sheet at the end.

Comment: @Argyll Many thanks for this. I have used your formula here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HM0tI3u3ewLNS8RPTbOyzvO1yEhffJnbjeMo1meg8mQ/edit#gid=1512335937. It copies down as expected, and the first value (-0.04%) is as expected. The second value (for MSFT) is however expected to be =(370.87/374.69)-1 = -1.02%, but the formula returns 101.84%? I have calcualted the different parts separately, and see no reason why it would return a wrong value. Everything in the formula seems correct. Do you know what goes wrong?

Comment: That is strange. Have you tried dragging down the same formula without `arrayformula`? Does it produce the correct results? In any case, if `arrayformula` and `index` do not work together. You will have to use `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot provide an array to the row and column parameters of the `INDEX` function, use [`MAP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) instead:

**YTD**

```cpp
=MAP(B2:B,C2:C,LAMBDA(idx,price,IF(OR(idx="",price=""),,price/INDEX(stockPrices!B2:J,I6,idx)-1)))
```

**1-Year-Change**

```cpp
=MAP(B2:B,C2:C,LAMBDA(idx,price,IF(OR(idx="",price=""),,price/INDEX(stockPrices!B2:J,I8,idx)-1)))
```

**5-Year-Change**

```cpp
=MAP(B2:B,C2:C,LAMBDA(idx,price,IF(OR(idx="",price=""),,price/INDEX(stockPrices!B2:J,I9,idx)-1)))
```

Note that I removed the `*100` and changed the cells formatting to "percent" instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. As a last question, I have added in column B a 5 year sparkline: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HM0tI3u3ewLNS8RPTbOyzvO1yEhffJnbjeMo1meg8mQ/edit#gid=2013906764. Is there a similar way to copy down sparklines as well?

Comment: please create a new post with the new question.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77790082/how-to-create-a-sparkline-that-copies-down-to-all-other-rows